# Why is the result different for same dataset in torchtext.legecy.text when i change the position of data in the csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to learn PyTorch NLP basic text classification and following Lazy Programmer's Tutorial and I got a different result from the tutorial and when I tried to change the data, I encountered a strange change in the output.

```py
import torchtext.legacy.data as ttd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


data = {
    'label':[0, 1,1 ],
    'data':[   'ham and eggs or just  morning',
            'I like eggs and ham.',
            'Eggs I like!',
          
           
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('thedata.csv', index=False)
TEXT = ttd.Field(
    sequential =True,
    batch_first =True,
    lower = True,
    tokenize ='spacy',
    pad_first = True
)
LABEL = ttd.Field(
    sequential=False,
    use_vocab=False,
    is_target  =True
)

dataset = ttd.TabularDataset(
    path = 'thedata.csv',
    format ='csv',
    skip_header=True,
    fields = [
              ('label', LABEL),
              ('data',TEXT)
    ]
)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset.split()
TEXT.build_vocab(train_dataset,)
vocab = TEXT.vocab
vocab.stoi
```

This is my first type of code and in the data, if you see i have used "'ham and eggs or just  morning'," in index 1. So after running the code, at last when i run vocab.stoi, I get the following output.
[The output for the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wquff.png)

```py
import torchtext.legacy.data as ttd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


data = {
    'label':[0, 1,1 ],
    'data':[   
            'I like eggs and ham.',
            'Eggs I like!',
'ham and eggs or just  morning',
          
           
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('thedata.csv', index=False)
TEXT = ttd.Field(
    sequential =True,
    batch_first =True,
    lower = True,
    tokenize ='spacy',
    pad_first = True
)
LABEL = ttd.Field(
    sequential=False,
    use_vocab=False,
    is_target  =True
)

dataset = ttd.TabularDataset(
    path = 'thedata.csv',
    format ='csv',
    skip_header=True,
    fields = [
              ('label', LABEL),
              ('data',TEXT)
    ]
)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset.split()
TEXT.build_vocab(train_dataset,)
vocab = TEXT.vocab
vocab.stoi
```

Now In the second code, I have change the index of data "'ham and eggs or just  morning'," in third index, now if I run the code then I get different output for vocab.stoi
[output for the second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86g5m.png).
I want to know the reason for this and how vocab_build works in PyTorch.
Plus, this is my first question, if the question is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use random seed for getting the same result for all of your runs (and also for comparing the results for your changes made in the model). The part of your code that should get the seed is dataset split function. as the [documentation](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Dataset.split) says, something like this:

```
_seed = 2021
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset.split(random_state=_seed)
```